# How to detect signals at the serial COM1 port?

Tags: java, serial-port

I have a infrared device (both transmitter and receiver). I've connected the receiver to the serial COM port and I send IR signals using the transmitter.

I'd like to monitor theese signals and whenever there is no signal, invoke another thread (sms sending code).

If I check the signals on hiperterminal, I get some unreadable values.

What should I look for as a `NO CARRIER` value to see if there is no data being recieved so I execute the second thread?

e.g

```
if(signals!=null)
{
    //do nothin
} 
else
{
    //thread2();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head over to [rxtx.org](http://rxtx.org/) for a free serial port library for Java under Windows, Linux or OSX.  All the details and sample code can be found in [this WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java).

The section on events, like getting notifications on control signal changes, is [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java#Event_Driven_Serial_Communication)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should read The [Java comm API documentation](http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/).

Also, look at [this code example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/OpenaserialportusingJavaCommunications.htm).

We'd need more information as to help you with the exact implementation details of your IR reciever.

Comment: @unknown - I think you need to work on your communication skills before moving onto another language. Sorry, but your shorthand typing is something that doesn't belong in a professional programming community.

Comment: i dont want the code to choose the port...i wat the code to read signals coming at a particular port.thnx

Comment: sorry mr.rob!actually my net is slow and i make up for it using shorthand,but wat you said is very true and i apologise for being so irrisponsible and thank you for making m aware.thank you very much.

Comment: @unknown have you at least checked the link I gave in my reply and especially the freshly added pointer to the section on event-driven communication?

Comment: yes sir,fvu. i am trying to go through it and i will see if i can get the desired information from the link you have provided.will be back here soon after two more days,i am having exams from tomorrow.thank you.